# Presentations of discrete subgroups of $\textrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory, geometric-group-theory, low-dimensional-topology, lattices-in-lie-groups

It is well known that geometrically finite Fuchsian groups, or finitely generated discrete subgroups of $\textrm{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$ can be classified up to isomorphism by their signature $[g,s;m_1,\dots,m_r]$ which define a presentation

$\Gamma = \left\langle a_1,b_1,\dots,a_g,b_g,c_1\dots,c_s,d_1,\dots,d_r\ |\ d_1^{m_1}=\dots=d_r^{m_r}=\prod_{i=1}^g[a_i,b_i]\prod_{j=1}^{r}d_j\prod_{k=1}^sc_k=1 \right\rangle.$

Does there exist a similar presentation for discrete subgroups of $\textrm{PGL}_2(\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: What do you know about orbifolds? For instance, do you know how to derive that presentation from the form of the quotient orbifold $\mathbb H^2 / \Gamma$?

Comment: I'm familiar with Poincaré's polygon theorem for fundamental domains of Fuchsian groups.  However, I'm not sure how to generalise the version I've seen to other quotient spaces.

Comment: You may want to read Macbeath's paper "The Classification of Non-Euclidean Plane Crystallographic Groups"; it contains presentations of NEC groups and much more; https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9AB398CB5C92F95433B1801807512AF2/S0008414X00055164a.pdf/classification_of_noneuclidean_plane_crystallographic_groups.pdf

Comment: @MoisheKohan that is excellent and definitely covers what I'm looking for

Comment: @MoisheKohan: That would be a good thing to post as an answer. I searched a while on the site here to see if there was already an appropriate answer, and found none.

Comment: @YCor I was being too hasty with the question, edited.

Comment: Is the difference in the non-orientable case, that $a_1,\dots,b_g$ is replaced with $u_1,\dots, u_g$ and $\prod [a_i,b_i]$ is replaced with $\prod u_i^2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geometrically speaking, $PGL(2,{\mathbb R})$ is the full isometry group of the hyperbolic plane ${\mathbb H}^2$. NEC (Noneuclidean crystallographic) groups are discrete isometry groups of ${\mathbb H}^2$ acting cocompactly.

You may want to read Macbeath's paper "[The Classification of Non-Euclidean Plane Crystallographic Groups](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/9AB398CB5C92F95433B1801807512AF2/S0008414X00055164a.pdf/classification_of_noneuclidean_plane_crystallographic_groups.pdf)"; it contains presentations of NEC groups and much more. The issue, however, is that the paper deals only NEC groups. One can write down a general presentation for geometrically finite isometry groups of the hyperbolic plane by taking Macbeath's presentations and declaring some of the exponents $m_i$ to be zero. (There will be a few exceptional cases that will be missing: These are finite extensions of cyclic groups.) The proof that this is a complete list of presentations will be essentially the same as in Macbeath's paper.